# With a single serial link, how to read continuous data every second (polling), and do other queries in the meantime?

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, pyserial, polling

I communicate with a hardware device via serial link RS232 (no other option available).

- I need to continuously poll some data "foo", every second (if possible).
- Sometimes I also need to ask the device for other data, such as "bar" and "baz"

Of course, since it's a single serial link (and no high-level interface like HTTP), I cannot do both at the same time just by using 2 different threads:  it's important to check that no concurrent data is being sent at the same time through the same wire.

This is my current solution:

```
class Device:
    def __init__(self):
        self.serial_port = serial.Serial(port="COM1", baudrate=9600, parity="N", stopbits=1)
        self.start_foo_polling()

    def start_foo_polling(self):
        self.foo_polling = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.get_foo_thread).start()

    def get_foo_thread(self):
        while self.foo_polling:
            self.serial_port.write(b"QUERY_FOO")
            data = self.serial_port.read(8)    # then, do something with data!
            time.sleep(1)
       
    def stop_foo_polling(self):
        self.foo_polling = False

    def query_bar(self):
        rerun_foo_polling = False                             # *
        if self.foo_polling:                                  # *
            rerun_foo_polling = True                          # *
            self.stop_foo_polling()                           # *
            time.sleep(1)   # wait for the thread to finish   # *   
        self.serial_port.write(b"QUERY_BAR")
        data = self.serial_port.read(8)
        if rerun_foo_polling:                                 # *
            self.start_foo_polling()                          # *

d = Device()
time.sleep(3.9)
d.query_bar()
```

but it would require some code duplication of the lines (*) for `def query_baz(self): ...`, and more generally it does not seem optimal.

**What is the standard serial link solution to handle this concurrency problem?**

Comment: This is not a complicated communications problem as you suggest. There's a simple request-response dialog for the protocol between the master and slave units. The master simply has to decide whether to issue the periodic `foo` request, or a random `bar` or `baz` request. It is just a simple decision to make, and does not involve "*serial link*" or "*concurrency*" considerations. Create a higher-level abstraction that allows only a single, active request to be pending at a time. Don't try to control this at the serial port level, which only needs to handle a simple one request &  one response.

Comment: @sawdust It is somehow a serial / concurrency question. If the device had a HTTP server, I would just do `while True: requests.get("/foo"); time.sleep(1)` in one thread, and the random requests `bar` and `baz` in another thread, and it would be super simple. Here the fact that 2 requests cannot take the same wire at the same time makes it more complicated. Maybe I can make my question clearer this way: *how to make a higher-level abstraction allowing me to just do `while True: device.ask_foo(); time.sleep(1)`  in one thread and some random requests in another thread?

Comment: "*how to make a higher-level abstraction ...*" -- You simply need a task/thread that accepts a request, either periodic or random. That request is sent to the device using the serial port. Either a response is received or a timeout occurs, so the request completes or fails. This task/thread is then ready to handle a new request. No contention or "*concurrency*" whatsoever to worry about on the serial port.

Comment: @sawdust Just to be more precise, does the abstraction you have in mind make possible the latest code block I just edited (with 2 threads)?

Comment: I've collected my thoughts in an answer to [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541607/high-level-abstraction-for-serial-communication/77546261#77546261). My original focus on a separate thread to perform all serial port write & reads led me to mis-state that there is "no contention". Hope my answer clears that up.